# Having one context dependent caller for different functions of similar or same arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two sets of input data (`data_p`, `data_q`) that I want to operate the same sequence of functions (`foo`, `bar`) on, however, as the inputs are different, the meaning of the functions change for each, so there's actually more functions (`foo_mode_p`, `foo_mode_q`, sim for `bar`). I would like to initialize the data as well as a `mode` parameter and run the relevant functions with arguments `data_p` and `mode` and call a general `foo` or `bar`.

My MWE is a bunch of if statements to check if the mode is valid, then to make the function call based on the mode.

```py
# different arg types but does foo to x,y
def foo_mode_p(x,y):
    return x+y
def foo_mode_q(x,y):
    p,q = x
    return p*q-y
def foo(mode, x,y):
    if mode=='p':
        return foo_mode_p(x,y)
    if mode=='q':
        return foo_mode_q(x,y)
    else:
       raise KeyError('`mode` not `p` or `q`')


# same arg types and does bar to u,v
def bar_mode_p(u,v):
    return u-v
def bar_mode_q(u,v):
    return u*v
def bar(mode, x,y):
    if mode=='p':
        return bar_mode_p(x,y)
    if mode=='q':
        return bar_mode_q(x,y)
    else:
       raise KeyError('`mode` not `p` or `q`')

# call the functions in sequence
def call_funcs(mode, a, b):
    c = foo(mode, a, b)
    d = bar(mode, c, b)
    print(f'mode {mode}:', c, d)
    return


# init and run p
mode = 'p'
a = 1
b = 3
call_funcs(mode, a, b) # *

# init and run q
mode = 'q'
a = (2,3)
b = 2
call_funcs(mode, a, b) # same call as at *
```

---

Points to note

- for every `foo_mode_p`, there is a `foo_mode_q` and vice versa
- input arguments don't always distinguish mode p from q
- output arguments rarely distinguish mode p from q
- I would like the functions `foo`,`foo_mode_p`,`foo_mode_q` to be in a module separate from the main file containing `call_funcs` and the data initialization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out,

Using `getattr`, we can call functions by their names as a string. The call, `foo(x,y)`, has arguments that work for either, but will requires an extra argument for `mode` which can be handled with a decorator. The reason for the decorator is to not need to write the function selection code for `foo` and for `bar`. The decorator takes the name of the new function (in this instance `foo` or `bar`) and calls the right function which would have `'_mode_p'` or `'_mode_q'` appended.

```py
# this class will take the place of a module so that `getattr` works in a single file
class funcs:
    # different arg types but does foo to x,y
    def foo_mode_p(x,y):
        return x+y
    def foo_mode_q(x,y):
        p,q = x
        return p*q-y

    # same arg types and does bar to u,v
    def bar_mode_p(u,v):
        return u-v
    def bar_mode_q(u,v):
        return u*v

## decorator to enable multi_mode functionality for given function
def multi_mode(f):
    # change function call to start with mode, then take in all other input args
    def wrapper(mode, *args, **kwargs):
        # check if mode valid
        if (mode != 'p' and mode != 'q'):
            raise KeyError('`mode` not `p` or `q`')
        # return right function from `funcs` (or whatever module name is)
        return getattr(funcs, f.__name__ + '_mode_' + mode)(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper


## make multi_mode calls for foo and bar
# the decorator performs the entire task, so the function body is empty
@multi_mode
def foo(x,y):
    return None

@multi_mode
def bar(x,y):
    return None


# call the functions in sequence
def call_funcs(mode, a, b):
    c = foo(mode, a, b)
    d = bar(mode, c, b)
    print(f'mode {mode}:', c, d)
    return


# init and run p
mode = 'p'
a = 1
b = 3
call_funcs(mode, a, b) # *

# init and run q
mode = 'q'
a = (2,3)
b = 2
call_funcs(mode, a, b) # same call as at *
```